# How to Save excel pages file with a loop?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, writer

i would like to save a different dataframe in different excel pages withb a simpler loop.
How can i construct correctly this loop?

my Currently codes are:

```
for fund in list(read_ex.keys()):
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
    data_2             .to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Df_ag')
    read_ex[fund]      .to_excel(writer, sheet_name= fund[:28])
    writer.save()
```

but the returns are only two page: the data_2 and the last in the loop.
Thank you for your time!

Imopla

Comment: Just move the ExcelWriter(), the first to_excel() and save() outside the loop.

Comment: Can you reply using the "Answer" command ? Thks

Answer (score 1):

For future readers:

I have been resolved this quastion in this way:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
data_2             .to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'Df_ag')

for fund in list(read_ex.keys()):
    read_ex[fund]      .to_excel(writer, sheet_name= fund[:28]) 
 
writer.save()
```